# Instruments Allocations Tool and OpenGL

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

According to Instruments' Allocations Tool and several heapshots, my `createFramebuffer` routine is responsible for leaking 1 MB of memory. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. But I'm also not sure if understand the output correctly. Instrument points me to the line containing `glCheckFramebufferStatusOES`. How can this function possibly leak memory?

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer (%d, %d) object for SizeView %x", backingWidth, backingHeight,glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)destroyFramebuffer {
    glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    viewFramebuffer = 0;
    glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
    viewRenderbuffer = 0;
}
```